# Upload Two Apk with same package and App Name in play store

Tags: android, google-play, package, apk

I want to upload  two apk with same package name and App name based on country (App have different features) on play store ,is there any possible to do this.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Once the apk is published, the `packageName` gets "locked", meaning if you want to publish 2 different apk with the same package name, an error will be thrown stating that package name already exists. You could ask google to "delete" the previous one, but I don't know if they even are allowed to do that.